# MySQL: Fail to extract a `digits` key from JSON field

Tags: mysql, json

In MySQL5.7, the following query with **$.4** would failed

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"id": 14, "4": "Aztalan"}', '$.4');
                                 ^                 ^^^
```

But change **$.4** to **$.name** would be okay

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"id": 14, "name": "Aztalan"}', '$.name');
                                 ^^^^                 ^^^^^^
```

Anybody could tell why? and how to extract an item of type string which is consist of digits from **JSON** field?

Comment: Still not work, but wow, `'$."4"'` is okay

Comment: Hey, nice find! You should answer your own question

Comment: FYI, the documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-path-syntax.html) ~ *"Names of keys must be **double-quoted strings** or valid ECMAScript identifiers"*